# Margin left/right behaving differently on Chrome & Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome

I have a div (Facebook comments plugin, for what it's worth) styled with only the following CSS.

```
div.fb-comments
{
margin-left:30%;
margin-right:30%;
}
```

On Chrome, this puts the `<div>` in the center of the screen. However, on Firefox, it remains at the left. Why might this be?

Comment: Do you have a defined width for this element?

Comment: No I don't. The only definition with the plugin was "data-width" which was for the inside stuff, not for the whole div.

Comment: Then you should/could define a width for this, then put margin-left and right to "auto". If you want it centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by YoannM, I defined a width for this element and it solved the problem. Thanks!